# How to create policy for user in system schema in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I logged in as system and coded this:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPHOLIDAY(
    EmpNo NUMBER(5),
    m_Name VARCHAR2(60),
    Holiday DATE
);
-- then i created 3 users:
ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = TRUE;

CREATE USER Hann IDENTIFIED BY HANN;
CREATE USER Annu IDENTIFIED BY ANNU;
CREATE USER Theota IDENTIFIED BY THEOTA;

GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Hann;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Annu;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Theota;
```

Then i want to create policy like this:

1- 'Annu' can only SEE and Edit row of EMPHOLIDAY that has 'EmpNo' = 2.

2- 'Theota' can't see or edit EMPHOLIDAY.

3- 'Hann' can see all rows of EMPHOLDAY, but only can edit rows that have 'Holiday' >= CURRENT DATE.

I create the second policy like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION policy_2(
    p_schema IN VARCHAR2,
    P_object IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'USER != ''Theota''';
END;
/
BEGIN DBMS_RLS.add_policy(
    object_schema => 'system',
    object_name => 'EMPHOLIDAY',
    policy_name => 'personalInfo',
    policy_function => 'policy_2',
    statement_types => 'SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT',
    update_check => TRUE
);
END;
```

And it worked. But for 2 other policies, i tried to change **RETURN** statement in **POLICY_2** and **statement_types** some times but this seems not the right ways. Can someone help me solve these problems? Thanks alot.

Comment: Please do not create objects in the system schema. This space is reserved for the database, along with sys.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Underscore parameters are to be used only at the direction of Oracle support - ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = TRUE;

Comment: Ok thanks. But if i assumed that 'system' is replace by another user (not the 3 above), can you help me to fixed this code?

Comment: About the 'alter session', i'm willing to use it because it allows me not to add C## before the 'username' that i want to create.

Comment: So even worse, you're creating users in the Container Database. Full Stop. Don't do this. Find your pluggable database, and login there to do your schema development.

Comment: Nothing in your code shows the objects being created anywhere other than the system schema.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But i mean, in the 'OBJECT_SCHEMA', if i change 'system' to another name, can you help me solved the problems, please?

Comment: I mean, a user is owner of EMPHOLIDAY and he tried to write policy for Ann, Theota and Annu.

Comment: you need to get out of the container database first - that's why your users won't get created without that ALTER command.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith is "trick" will create an user with flag ORACLE_MAINTAINED='Y' meaning such a DB user was created Oracle itself rather than by client. (Which does not make much sense). Some monitoring tools like "New Reilc" recommend to create a monitoring user this way.

Comment: My main problems are not about the USERS but are how to create policies for them. Can you guys show me some examples?

Comment: _"My main problems are not about the USERS but are how to create policies for them."_  Did you stop to consider that perhaps your problem _flows from_ the convoluted way you are creating users?  I'd go back and recreate the problem , heeding _all_ of Jeff Smith's advice, then update your question to show that problem.  (BTW, if you didn't know, Jeff is a project manager at Oracle. He knows whereof he speaks). .